# Problem during installation PostgreSQL 12 and PgAdmin4 on Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 64-bit

Tags: postgresql, installation, linux-mint

I want to install PostgreSQL and PgAdmin4 on my Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 64-bit
My inxi info

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: MATE 1.24.0 info: mate-panel 
           wm: marco 1.24.0 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Portable System: Dell product: Inspiron 3542 v: N/A serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 8 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0KHNVP v: A04 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: A04 date: 08/05/2014 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 15.6 Wh condition: 27.7/41.4 Wh (67%) volts: 16.7/14.8 model: SMP-SDI2.8 DELL FW1MN31 
           type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Charging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-4005U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 13568 
           Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/1700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:0a16 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa compositor: marco v: 1.24.0 
           resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.8 compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           chip ID: 8086:0a0c 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:9c20 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-58-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n vendor: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 
           driver: bcma-pci-bridge v: N/A port: f040 bus ID: 06:00.0 chip ID: 14e4:4365 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169 v: kernel port: e000 
           bus ID: 07:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8136 
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 494.66 GiB used: 9.07 GiB (1.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABF050 size: 465.76 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s rotation: 5400 rpm 
           serial: <filter> rev: 1D scheme: GPT 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB model: USB DISK 3.0 size: 28.90 GiB serial: <filter> rev: PMAP scheme: MBR 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 95.62 GiB used: 8.97 GiB (9.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: 46.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:     Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 20.1 _Ulyssa_ - Release amd64 20210103]/ focal contrib main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyssa main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
           2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
Info:      Processes: 184 Uptime: 1h 14m Memory: 3.75 GiB used: 671.3 MiB (17.5%) Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 running in: mate-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

I followed the instruction from https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

I performed the instruction step by step and noticed Error messages in the log after step 3

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                       
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Ign:4 http://mirror.yandex.ru/linuxmint-packages ulyssa InRelease                     
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:6 http://mirror.yandex.ru/linuxmint-packages ulyssa Release
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [844 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [436 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [264 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [750 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [558 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [303 kB]                                                                           
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]                                                                        
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1 768 B]                                                                        
Hit:16 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                           
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                              
Ign:18 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ulyssa-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                    
Err:19 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ulyssa-pgdg Release                                                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
Hit:20 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                      
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,3 kB]                                                                            
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58,2 kB]                                                                        
Error: Timeout was reached                                                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ulyssa-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Then I checked repos using inxi -r

```
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/linuxmint-packages ulyssa main upstream import backport
           2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list 
           1: deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ulyssa-pgdg main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

When I made step 4 [c]sudo apt-get -y install postgresql[/c] I got next results:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 61709 (apt)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I checked 61709 process. It was

```
root       61709  0.0  0.0  80208  1600 ?        S    мар13   0:23 /usr/bin/apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Queries:

1. Should I remove preinstalled PostgreSQL and PgAdmin3 before installing v 12 and PgAdmin4?
2. What's wrong in the PosgreSQL installation process and how is it possible to get success?

Comment: Sine Mint isn't Ubuntu the instructions won't work directly. You'll need to manually modify the sources.list to have the correct release info. After that you can update and install again. If it says it's locked, another process is installing things and you'll have to wait for that to stop.

Comment: Could you give me step by step instruction what and how I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your Linux Mint Laptop/Server.
2. Backup your Database and remove old PostgreSQL and PgAdmin3.
3. Follow instructions from [here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-with-pgadmin4-on-linux-mint/) to install PostgreSQL.